# broken packages - libg11-mesa-dri:i386

Tags: apt, updates, package-management

happy new year!

Not so for my PC :o)
While installing the IA32-libs my PC ran into a broken package problem.
( The system is ubuntu 12.10 - 64 bit and I want to compile 32bit targets.)

The console output is vague about this but I did get more information out of the GUI update-manager:this is the output:

"De afhankelijkheden van de volgende pakketten konden niet geïnstalleerd worden:

libgl1-mesa-dri:i386: Depends: libgcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1) maar 1:4.7.2-2ubuntu1 is geïnstalleerd"

That's Dutch for: libgl1-mesa depends on libgcc1 1.4.1.1 but 1.4.7.2 is already installed on my system.

The real problem is the inability for apt-get to overcome this because I can't perform any updates, not by the console nor the GUI update manager. So My PC is basically stuck.

I tried ; apt-get install -f, remove, autoremove, update, upgrade. and so on.

Has someone an idea how to solve this?

many thanks
rm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found an answer to my own question:

http://www.webupd8.org/2011/02/fix-dpkg-error-trying-to-overwrite-x.html

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/yourbrokenpackage.deb
```

then:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

That did the trick for me.but I really don't know what really happened to the broken files.
The --force-help file says :

"Overwrite    Overwrite a file from one package with another"

So, I don't know but at least my update manager is back ;o)